# Text Widget Links Not Working

Tags: widgets, html, links, widget-text

I am trying to add a simple link to an 'About' page in a Sidebar Text Widget but when I test it the link does not work and I get an error on the linked page:

"The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

I know the link works because if I paste it directly into the browser the page comes up.

And I am pretty sure the html is correct for the link in the Text Widget:

```
<a href=”http://www.somesite.com”>Some Site</a>
```

Any ideas?

The site Theme I am using is Avani - if that makes any difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the right double quotation mark `”` instead of the quotation mark `"`, use it like this:

```
<a href="http://www.somesite.com">Some Site</a>
```

they look very similar but are different chars.